# C# LINQ - Union() the Group()-results

Tags: c#, linq, union, grouping

I have a list of Objects, where every object has a "Name" and different other stuff. I want to filter out those objects who don't have a unique name in that List.

Is there a LINQ Statement where I can "Union()" all the resulting groups and just return a IEnumerable of my objects?

Like

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> Results = (from x in Objects 
                                 group x by x.Name into g
                                 where g.Count() > 1
                                 select g)
                                 .COMBINE_OR_WHATEVER();
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want all properties from `Objects` where there the value of Name property only appears once?  Why are you checking for a `Count() > 1`, shouldn't it be `Count() = 1`?

Comment: @scott.korin: It depends what he means by "filter out". I guess it could mean either "keep" or "remove" depending on your perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> Results = (from x in Objects 
                                 group x by x.Name into g
                                 where g.Count() > 1
                                 select g)
                                 .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want only the object with unique names ("*I want to **filter out** those objects who **don't have** a unique name in that List*"):

```
var result = Objects.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```